insmod "Invalid module format" with Debian 11 on RockChip RK3568 system after building module from source
I have no USB serial converters installed on my RK3568 system, so I am trying to build them from the kernel sources. I am specifically trying to build ch341.ko and ftdi_sio.ko. None of these modules are even present on my system.
uname -r == 4.19.232

I downloaded (wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.19.232.tar.xz) and installed the 4.19.232 kernel sources on the target system. After that I copied the config file stored on the system to my kernel source folder (/home/linaro/linux).
At the top, the config file has the comment
# Linux/arm64 4.19.232 Kernel Configuration

Among others, the config file contains the lines
CONFIG_MODVERSIONS=y
CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_CH341=m
CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_FTDI_SIO=m

In my kernel source folder, I invoked
make ARCH=arm64 oldconfig
make ARCH=arm64 modules_prepare
make ARCH=arm64 -C . M=drivers/usb/serial modules

All modules are being built. I am building on the target system, so no cross compile, the compile is native.
vermagic returned by "modinfo drivers/usb/serial/ftdi_sio.ko" is
4.19.232 SMP mod_unload modversions aarch64

.
grep -E 'VERSION|PATCHLEVEL|SUBLEVEL|EXTRAVERSION' Makefile

returns VERSION = 4, PATCHLEVEL = 19, SUBLEVEL = 232, EXTRAVERSION =, (so no EXTRAVERSION) which obviously is what is needed.
How do I fix this?

You downloaded a vanilla archive when you need the kernel source from the vendor. Otherwise you have to update the entire kernel on the target.

As for architecture worries the arm64 is a Linux kernel convention, the real architecture is aarch64, i.o.w. there is nothing wrong.

@0andriy: I don't quite understand what difference that makes. It's the kernel source with the correct version number, using the installed kernel's config file for building the modules. I have to say that I am absolutely no linux kernel expert. I'm just a dev trying to get a driver I need to run my app on the system. I also couldn't find the exact 4.19.232 kernel sources in RockChip's linux kernel repository.

It makes the difference in how modules are matching the (running) kernel and vice versa. If you don’t have sources, you need to ask for them, they have to provide it, otherwise you may sue the company for violating GPL.
